# Ticks count is not consistent in nvd3 line chart.

Tags: angular

Ticks count is not consistent. I have a use case where i have to show all the date on the x-axis but y-axis may not have value for that date.Also, line should be continuous.
For example lets i have a value for 1/03/2018 and then next value is present for 5/03/2018.Now axis should have all the values for date from 1st march to 5th march but it should also connect data from 1st to 5th march without any gap.
I am using NVD3 library for line chart.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. So what you can do is bind the value that you want display on the x-axis in the data object that you have used for nvd3 graph.Now you can show that using tickvalues function of graphs.
Let me know if it helps anyone or need further assistance at the code level.